# How do I load id element when clicking url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load content inside ID when i click on a url that defined like this : /route/#id.

What I have right now doesn't work when I'm switching between /route/#id1 and /route#id2.  When I first click on the link it works. The id element show up. But when I switch to another url from the same page, the id element doesn't display. It just shows a blank page

urls

```
<li class="dropdown nav_about {$activeBrands}">BRANDS
    <ul class='sub-menu'>
        <li> <a href="{$rootDir}brands/#link1"> link1 </a></li>
        <li> <a href="{$rootDir}brands/#link2"> link2 </a>       </li>
    </ul> 
</li>
```

content

```
<div id="link1" style="display:none;">
   content
</div>
<div id="link2" style="display:none;">
   content
</div>
```

script

```
<script>
$(function(){   
    var url = window.location.href;
    console.log(url);
    var urlId = url.match(/#.*/)[0];
    showDiv(urlId);

});
function showDiv(option){
    $(option).show();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are brands/#link1 and brands/#link2 two pages?

Comment: they are in the same page

Comment: Then `<li class="dropdown nav_about {$activeBrands}">BRANDS
    <ul class='sub-menu'>
        <li> <a href="{$rootDir}brands/#link1"> link1 </a></li>
        <li> <a href="{$rootDir}brands/#link2"> link2 </a>       </li>
    </ul> 
</li>` is also in the same page?

Comment: its passed in as the header. So yeah its in the same page

Comment: The page with the url `{$rootDir}brands/` won't reload when you click the  `<a href="{$rootDir}brands/#link">` tags

Comment: I think thats the case. If I refresh the page it works

Answer (score 1):

You should use `window.location.hash` instead.

For a url

```
http://www.domain.com/somepage?#asf1234
```

the value of `window.location.hash` will be

```
#asf1234
```

> Note that `#` is the first character

Comment: why not? when you load the page, instead of checking `window.location.href` you should check `window.location.hash` and `showId()` according to the one that in the hash.